# Isolated unit tests with provider dependencies in Angular2 final

Tags: unit-testing, angular

In angular2 isolated unit tests (no testbed available) I want to provide a service with dependencies. The docs on testing say they don't prepare dependendy injection provides and create instances with new. The example from the docs lists:

```
let service: FancyService;
beforeEach(() => { service = new FancyService(); });
```

But what if my service has dependencies itself ? For example my service 'ClientService' that I want to instantiate depends on the Http module(, which itself depends on 'ConnectionBackend' and 'RequestOptions') and another custom service called 'LoginService'. On angular2 rc4 I would write:

```
beforeEach(() => addProviders([
    {provide: ClientsService, useClass: ClientsServiceMock},
    LoginService,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]));
```

Apparently in Angular2 final (2.0.0) the addProviders from @angular/core/testing is not available anymore.

If I want to instantiate with 'new' I have to resolve all dependencies recursively. How to handle this correctly ??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the `TestBed` for this. `HTTP_PROVIDERS` is no longer available, as all the providers are contained in the `HttpModule`. So you would need to import that into the `TestBed`. Without using the `TestBed` you could create an independent injector, but that would take adding all the providers manually. It's not really worth it. The test would look something like

```
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
// all other HTTP related stuff from `@angular/http`

let service: FancyService;
let backend: MockBackend;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpModule ],
    providers: [
      FancyService, LoginService, MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions,
      {provide: ClientsService, useClass: ClientsServiceMock},
      {
        provide: Http,
        deps: [ MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions ],
        useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, options: BaseRequestOptions) => {
          return new Http(backend, options);
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  service = TestBed.get(FancyService);
  backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);
});

it('..', async(() => {
  backend.connections.subscribe((conn: MockConnection) => {
    let resOptions = new ResponseOptions({ body: someJsonBody });
    let res = new Response(resOptions);
    conn.mockRespond(res);
  });

  service.getSomething().subscribe(res => {
    expect(res.json()).toBe(someBody);
  });
}));
```

Here, we're subscribing the `MockBackend.connections`. Anytime someone make an `Http` request, a connection will come through, where we can send back a mock response.